# How does < and > operators works

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-objects

I recently got into a golf kata that asked to check if a letter is uppercase or not in no more than 9 characters.

The users answers were kind of scary (those example also works with `>` in reverse order):

```js
f=s=>s<{}
```

```js
f=c=>c<{}
```

```js
f=_=>_<f
```

```js
f=Z=>Z<f
```

Some variable names don't works with `f`:

```js
f=a=>a<f
```

```js
f=z=>z<f
```

Why and how does `<` and `>` operators works when comparing functions to basic strings? Maybe pointers comparison?

Try by yourself:

```js
// working
f1=s=>s<{}
f2=c=>c<{}
f3=_=>_<f3
f4=Z=>Z<f4

// not working
f5=s=>s<f5

console.log('f1', f1('A'))
console.log('f1', f1('a'))

console.log('f2', f2('A'))
console.log('f2', f2('a'))

console.log('f3', f3('A'))
console.log('f3', f3('a'))

console.log('f4', f4('A'))
console.log('f4', f4('a'))

console.log('f5', f5('A'))
console.log('f5', f5('a'))
```

Comment: it's just for and like arithmetic in the conditionals

Comment: It’s all explained in the [spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing a string to `{}` is effectively comparing the string to the results of `({}).toString()`, which is always `"[object Object]"`. The important part is the `[` character, which is the first code point after the last upper-case letter (`Z`). Thus, if you know that the input string is *some* letter, comparing to a string beginning with `[` will tell you that it's an upper-case letter.

To be clear,

```
s => s<{}
```

is effectively

```
s => s<"[object Object]"
```

It has nothing to do with variable names chosen when you use an object (`{}`), but it's important for function-reference versions. In those, the "_" is important because it's a character after "Z" but before all the lower-case letters.

Comment: Also for the confusion with f5 not working, it's because f5.toString() would start with 's'

Comment: But why does `f3` and `f4` works while `f5` doesn't?

Comment: @D.Nathanael abd `f3` works because "_" comes after all the upper-case letters  in the encoding sequence. Note that you would be crazy to use any of those in actual production code in almost any circumstance.

Comment: I still don't understand why f5 doesn't works with the parameter named as `s`. Don't worry, this monstrosity won't go on production haha!

Comment: The first character of the "stringified" version of `f5` is "s", meaning that I was completely wrong about what I said in the answer (I'll edit it).  "a" is less than "s".

Comment: Oh ok! So the stringified version of `f5` is what is compared to the string! Thanks you for your explanation :)

Answer (score -3):

The operator `>` and `<` returns `true` or `false` depending on the two value around the operator. if you try to assign a type than is not compatible to a boolean then it will not work

Comment: This doesn't really make a lot of sense.